# Do Stack Exchange sites log search terms?

Tags: discussion, search, site-analytics

Are the terms from searches on Stack Exchange sites logged, and if so could users or just Stack Exchange gurus (25000+ rep) browse them? If not, is it because the data would present privacy concerns or be overly difficult to analyze?

I ask because a recent search for a topic on the Biology site yielded no results, and I was left wondering whether there is any community interest in that topic. In my case, I could just come up with a question for the topic and see how the answers and comments play out, but I'm sure there are other applications for the search data that I haven't thought of.

Comment: cross-site related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73713/158100